# All Two by Two Matrices Satisfy a Certain Property Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $A$, $B$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists a real number $\lambda$ so that

$$ (AB-BA)^2 = \lambda I $$

I can do this problem using brute force (i.e. looking at $A$ and $B$ element-wise), but I know there has to be a different, clever way. It was on an old qualifier, and I know they would not be looking for a solution using element wise entries.

Comment: For future reference: use \times when you want to write $p\times q$ matrices. It reads much nicer than $2\mathrm{x}2$.

Comment: this is an instance of the cayley-hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Note that $\operatorname{trace}(AB - BA) = 0$.  What does this tell you about the eigenvalues of $AB - BA$?  Alternatively, what does this tell you about the characteristic polynomial of $AB - BA$?

Comment: Does this rely on existence of Jordan form? Alternatively, is this mentioned matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: @fish.frog not necessarily. The most reductionist approach I can think of along the lines of my hint is to use the eigenvalues (which must exist over $\Bbb C$) to find the characteristic polynomial, then apply Cayley Hamilton.

Comment: @fish.frog alternatively, we can avoid eigenvalues altogether if we note that the characteristic polynomial always has the form $$x^2-\operatorname{trace}(M)x + \det(M)$$

Answer (score 4):

This follows directly if you apply Cayley-Hamilton theorem to the matrix $AB-BA$.

Answer (score 1):

Still involves some brute force, but one simplification you can make is to say that $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is the commutator ideal of $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ so this is equivalent to the statement that for every $A \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ there is a $\lambda$ such that $A^2 = \lambda I$.

Still have to do that last part with brute force, but at least you're only dealing with $3$ variables and $1$ matrix operation, instead of $8$ variables and $4$ matrix operations.

Comment: Show that every $A \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ satisfies $\operatorname{adj} A = -A$. This is completely painless.